# How to create a local variable in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very very new to programming and I understand this is quite a dumb question but I'm not sure how to search for the answer to it.

For an assignment, we have been limited to 2 or less global variables.

I'm trying to do this:

```
for x in range(0,5):
    etc, etc
```

I have tried printing global() and I'm pretty sure this makes x a global variable - is there a way to create a local variable in this case or do I just have to work around it?

Comment: x is locally scoped to the loop, it's not global

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear. Give a longer code sample. Local variables are not restricted to a for loop but to a function or a method.

Comment: While not necessarily `global` @OneCricketeer you will find `x` still in scope after the loop -- it is not scoped to the loop.

Comment: Global variables are defined by the `global` statement when changed within a function.  Challenge yourself to use *none*.  In broad terms, [global variables are dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/6340496)..

Comment: 'local' would mean local to a function. If you don't use any function, your variables will be global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have loop variables in a scope other than the loop's scope, simply because the variable is defined in the same line/indentation as the `for` loop. If the `for` loop is in the global scope, then so too will the loop variable. However, if your limitation is only on *global* variables, the `for` loop could be placed within a non-global scope, such as a function, like so:

```
def loop():
    for x in range(0, 5):
        ...
```

This workaround, however, likely goes against the spirit of your assignment, so use with care.

As a note, this approach still creates a global variable, in this case a function, but whether or not that counts would likely depend on the semantics of the assignment. "Use with care" should more likely be "don't use at all."

Comment: This has, however, created a global variable called `loop`.